# Trivial Fundamental Group and Orientation

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

Maybe it is an easy question but I cannot figure out.

If the fundamental group of (you may assume compact) an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ is trivial, i.e., $$\pi_1(M)=0,$$ then can we conclude that $M$ is orientable?

Comment: (Assuming $M$ is connected so you can talk about $\pi_1(M)$) Yes.  The orientable double cover of $M$ is two disjoint copies of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is non-orientable, the [orientable double cover](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability#Orientable_double_cover) of $M$ gives you a connected cover space of $M$ where each point has a two-point fiber. Thus the fundamental group of $M$ cannot be trivial.

Comment: What is the relationship between $\pi(M)$ and that of the orientable double cover? I don't understand how to complete the argument.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat If a space has trivial fundamental group, then the only connected covering space is itself. Since we can, for any non-orientable manifold, construct a _different_ connected covering space, they cannot have trivial fundamental groups. Specifically, given $p\in M$, there are two points in the cover that maps to $p$. A path between those two points gives a non-null loop in $M$.